# How to sum data and join columns using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to sum values in data

from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

but the problem is, the data doesn't add up but they like 11, 1111

here is my code:

```
df_data.insert(loc=2, column='Jumlah', value='1')
df_data.pivot_table(index='Kecamatan', columns='Status', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
```

And how I can make the columns only `KECAMATAN NEGATIF ODP ODPSELESAI OTG PDP`

Thank you guys.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) , also check dtypes if they are strings you might have to convert them first , post a complete example of the data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the value of the inserted column (*Jumlah*) is a **string**.
In the next instruction you attempt to generate a *pivot_table* **summing**
this column.

But if you attempt to *sum* text values, it actually means **concatenation**.

To put things right, change the first instruction to:

```
df_data.insert(loc=2, column='Jumlah', value=1)
```

i.e. remove apostrophes surrounding *1*.

Then this column will be of *int* type and will be summed as you wish.